# Can I keep the E-tech BlASSter that I got during Medical Mystery if I don't turn the quest in to Dr Zed?

Tags: borderlands-2

I want to keep the E-tech assault rifle that I got off of Dr. Mercy's body during the Medical Mystery quest, and so far I've been able to continue using it because I haven't turned the quest in to Dr. Zed.  However, I haven't left the game and have been pausing it when I stop for the day.  Will the weapon survive a game exit and load?  I've been afraid to try it because I love the gun!

Answer (score 2):

PS3 users beware... I exited and saved my game, and when I reloaded it, the BlASSter assault rifle was no longer in my possession.  The quest *Medical Mystery: X-Com-municate* still appears in my missions list as ready to turn in.  Drats!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mission-specific weapons will stay in your inventory until you turn in the mission. People often keep a quest active for certain end-game weapons, like the Grog Nozzle.

Comment: Well, I saved my game and when I reloaded, the assault rifle was gone from my inventory.  Damn!

Comment: I'm almost positive quest weapons don't occupy inventory space. Haven't played in awhile though so i could be wrong. And even if they did, whys it matter since you're using it anyways.

Comment: @Alan, what was the state of the quest? Some quests become "failed" if not completed in a single game, but they can be taken anew. I was pretty sure X-Com-municate is not one of those, though...

Comment: Indeed, no inventory slot is taken.

Comment: @OrcJMR The quest was still green as "ready to turn in", so you're correct that it's not one that becomes "failed".  I had it equipped when I exited the game and when I later loaded the game, it was gone completely, neither in my equipped list nor in any inventory slot.  My guess is that this is a game glitch, because it seems plausible that it should stay "yours" until you turn in the quest.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't above your list? Mission weapons do that.